# Differences between window.location.hash and $(window).location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any differences between `window.location.hash` and `$(window).location.hash`?

Comment: btw, it's $(window), not $(windows) :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences - jQuery will parse and preform a bunch of unnecessary operations on the object, so just doing `window.location.hash` is better.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping things like `this` or `window` inside a call to `$` is only useful when you want to use a jQuery method on the resulting object, since a call to `$` will return the object wrapped inside a jQuery object.  So, in this case, just use `window.location.hash`

Comment: I would consider this to be the answer: it explains the wrapping, but importantly it explains the VALUE (or anti-value) of $ wrapping.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one works, the other doesn't.

Doing `$(window)` will wrap the `window` object inside a `jQuery` object, and the `jQuery` object doesn't have a `location` property, so you will get `undefined` back. As you can't get the property `hash` (or any property) from `undefined`, the code ends with the error message `"$(window).location is undefined"`.